# Atomic operation in JAVA

Tags: java

I know why to use synchronization in Java, but I can´t find answer on this question:

```
do I need to synchronized an atomic operation?
```

If yes, why?

Comment: If you know why to use synchronization in Java, then you should be able to answer your own question. Think about what it means for an operation to be atomic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it really is atomic, then no.

You need synchronization to provide coherent state. Any atomic operation results in cohernt state by definition of being atomic.

Answer (score 3):

There are very few truly atomic operations in Java.  From the [Atomic Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) Java Tutorial:

- Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except `long` and `double`).
- Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared `volatile` (*including* `long` and `double` variables).

Note that synchronization is not just used for mutual exclusion, but it's also required for reliable communications between threads.  Even when you're dealing with data that is atomically readable and writable, there's no guarantee when, if ever, one thread will see a change made by another.  For this reason you need to either synchronize access to shared data, or make sure shared variables are declared `volatile`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be sure that your atomic operation does not expand to multiple read and update operations. Simple expressions like the increment and decrement operations do expand into multiple actions thus i++ and i-- are **not** atomic operations. Thus most times if you are reading and updating variable from multiple threads then you are better off using a synchronized methods.

More Details:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html